# Linear regression loss increasing

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I wrote a linear regression from scratch but the loss is increasing. My data are the areas and the prices (as labels) of the houston housing dataset. I tried multiple learning-rates (from 10 to 0.00000000001), but its still not working. With every epoch, my fit-line/function keeps moving further away from the data points. There must be something wrong with the functions I guess, but I cant figure out what. 
Here is an example of the loss:

```
loss: 0.5977188541860982
loss: 0.6003449724263221
loss: 0.6029841845821928
loss: 0.6056365560589673
loss: 0.6083021525886172
loss: 0.6109810402314608
loss: 0.6136732853778034
loss: 0.6163789547495854
loss: 0.6190981154020385
loss: 0.6218308347253524
loss: 0.6245771804463445
```

And here the code:

```
from preprocessing import load_csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# mean squared error
def MSE(y_prediction, y_true, deriv=(False, 1)):
    if deriv[0]:
        # deriv[1] is the  derivitive of the fit_function
        return 2 * np.mean(np.subtract(y_true, y_prediction) * deriv[1])
    return np.mean(np.square(np.subtract(y_true, y_prediction)))

# linear function
def fit_function(theta_0, theta_1, x):
    return theta_0 + (theta_1 * x)

# train model
def train(dataset, epochs=10, lr=0.01):
    # loadinh and normalizing the data
    x = (v := np.array(dataset["GrLivArea"].tolist()[:100])) / max(v)
    y = (l := np.array(dataset["SalePrice"].tolist()[:100])) / max(l)

    # y-intercept
    theta_0 = random.uniform(min(y), max(y))
    # slope
    theta_1 = random.uniform(-1, 1)

    for epoch in range(epochs):

        predictions = fit_function(theta_0, theta_1, x)
        loss = MSE(predictions, y)

        delta_theta_0 = MSE(predictions, y, deriv=(True, 1))
        delta_theta_1 = MSE(predictions, y, deriv=(True, x))

        theta_0 -= lr * delta_theta_0
        theta_1 -= lr * delta_theta_1

        print("\nloss:", loss)


    plt.style.use("ggplot")
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    x, predictions = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(x, predictions))))
    plt.plot(x, predictions, "b--")

    plt.show()


train(load_csv("dataset/houston_housing/single_variable_dataset/train.csv"), epochs=500, lr=0.001)
```

Here is the plot after 500 epochs.
[image: plot]

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite an old post, but I thought I'd give an answer anyway.

You flipped the sign on the MSE derivative:

```
def MSE(y_prediction, y_true, deriv=(False, 1)):
    if deriv[0]:
        return 2 * np.mean(np.subtract(y_prediction, y_true) * deriv[1])
    return np.mean(np.square(np.subtract(y_true, y_prediction)))
```

The partial derivatives w.r.t. you parameters are:

[image]

---

For conciseness:

```
def MSE(y_prediction, y_true, deriv=None):
    if deriv is not None:
        return 2 * np.mean((y_prediction - y_true)*deriv)
    return np.mean((y_prediction - y_true)**2)
```

Which allows you to get the derivatives without passing in a *tuple* with a flag:

```
delta_theta_0 = MSE(predictions, y, deriv=1)
delta_theta_1 = MSE(predictions, y, deriv=x)
```

---

Here's an example using [`sklearn.datasets.load_boston`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_boston.html) with `LSTAT` (*lower status of the population*) and `MEDV` (*Median value of owner-occupied homes in $1000's*) as target the last two data features as input and target respectively.

Trained with `epochs=10000` and `lr=0.001`:

[image]

Comment: hey, thanks for answering :) I solved it back then by keeping it ```y_true - y_pred``` and then multiplying with negative chain rule factor